# Animate View constraint across arc in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I wanna animate a UIButton that holds the score of progress,
this is the first state
[image]

and I wanna animate this button to a final state that is

[image]

I've used CAShapeLayer to make these arcs and
my code is

```
   let lineWidth: CGFloat = 12
        let score = 90

        let endAngle : CGFloat = .pi + (.pi * (CGFloat(score)/100))

        let center = view.center

        let progressPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)


        endPoint = progressPath.currentPoint

        let startPoint: CGPoint =  UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true).currentPoint
  let halfCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi*2, clockwise: true)
        let greyLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        greyLayer.strokeColor = greyColor
        greyLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        greyLayer.path = halfCirclePath.cgPath
        greyLayer.lineCap = .round
        greyLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        greyLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        greyLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        greyLayer.shadowOffset = .zero
        greyLayer.shadowRadius = 2

        view.layer.addSublayer(greyLayer)

        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.path = progressPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd =  1
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Best"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .red
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)

        view.addSubview(label)

        view.layer.addSublayer(label.layer)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive  = true

        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(scoreButton)

        scoreButton.setTitle(" \(score)% ", for: .normal)
  scoreButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        scoreButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        scoreButton.layer.shadowRadius = 8
        scoreButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        scoreButton.backgroundColor = .white
        scoreButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scoreButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: endPoint.y).isActive = true
        scoreButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: endPoint.x).isActive = true
```

for animating I'm using DispatchQueu.main.asyncAfter but can not change the constraint of ScoreButton and its not smooth

```
 
        let frameCount:CGFloat = 100

        for index in 0...Int(frameCount) {

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index)/Double(frameCount)) { [self] in
                self.shapeLayer.strokeEnd =  CGFloat(index )/frameCount
                let currentPoint = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi + (.pi * (CGFloat(index)/frameCount)), clockwise: true).currentPoint
                self.scoreButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: currentPoint.y).isActive = true
                self.scoreButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: currentPoint.x).isActive = true
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
```

and this Error Occures

```
[5220:309329] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a20050 H:|-(114.789)-[UIButton:0x140905810' 90% ']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x140a06100 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a21270 H:|-(314)-[UIButton:0x140905810' 90% ']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x140a06100 )>"
)
```

is there any smooth way to animate this UIButton that holds a score during the animation progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to animating a view/layer along a curved path is to use keyframe animation. Both UIView and CALayer support keyframe animations.

In your case, you should be able to use a UIView animation of the offset constant of your view's horizontal and vertical constraints.

You should be able to find tutorials on using UIView keyframe animation to animate a view along a curved path online.

Animating the arc will require creating a CABAsicAnimation to animate the strokeEnd property of a CAShapeLayer. Again, there are various tutorials online on how to do that. (I recently wrote an SO post on animating a checkmark that uses this technique.)

Answer (score 0):

You set constraints here

```
  scoreButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  scoreButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: endPoint.y).isActive = true
  scoreButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: endPoint.x).isActive = true
```

The create another cconflict ones here

```
 let currentPoint = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi + (.pi * (CGFloat(index)/frameCount)), clockwise: true).currentPoint 
 self.scoreButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: currentPoint.y).isActive = true
 self.scoreButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: currentPoint.x).isActive = true
```

You need to deactivate old ones before you add new ones , or change the constants only like this

```
var bottomCon,leadingCon:NSLayoutConstraint?
```

---

```
  scoreButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

  bottomCon = scoreButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: endPoint.y)
  bottomCon.isActive = true

  leadingCon = scoreButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: endPoint.x) 
  leadingCon.isActive = true
```

---

```
 self.bottomCon.constant = currentPoint.y 
 self.leadingCon.constant = currentPoint.x 
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

Comment: Tnx :) , its working very well , but its not smooth , is there any function to animate and monitor the progress ?